# How to know if targeted website contains private content?

Tags: php, session, private

I have developed a tool that creates a thumbnail of a webpage according to how the user visualizes it in his browser.

I would like to generate the thumbnail only once if all users see the same content. However, if content is customized or private (e.g. facebook home), the generated thumbnail will only be available for that specific user and not everyone.

My question is the following:
-How can I check if a web page contains private information or display to avoid trying to fetch them ?

My researches led me to think that if a https connection is used, the content is private. However, not all websites use https when data is private but not sensitive e.g. facebook uses http for your personal homepage.
I believe there is a way to check if php has logged a user via sessions to detect that user is in a login-type website.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance,
Gaël

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea to consider is using a social-filter.  GMail's spam-trap is a well-known example of this.  The idea would be that you would generate the best preview you could but then offer the user some sort of widget to mark the site-preview as inaccurate (ie: "Check this box if this site-preview is inaccurate" -- include sub-options where one reason would be "This page contains personal information depending on the user using it").  Then define an algorithm to determine how many people have to click the widget before you decide to stop serving up a pre-built preview of that site.

One drawback to this method is that it relies on large numbers of users using the site in order to be accurate -- while your tool is young and unused, this method method won't be very accurate.  Additionally, sites visited by few people will make it hard for this method to be accurate as well.

EDIT: one way to get beyond those problems would be to only PRE-generate previews based on frequency-of-access.  In other words, once a particular site starts become requested by enough users, THEN you start PRE-generating a preview -- including the widget, then, to allow users to tell you to stop pre-generating it.  That method might work since you would be guaranteed enough users would be using it to make the widget useful.

Comment: That's a great idea, I did not think about a solution on the user side as I was focused on the technical specifications. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You don't know how the web site is doing session management or otherwise identifying the user. It could be cookies, encoded in the URL or something else.

Answer (score 1):

> -How can I check if a web page contains private information or display to avoid trying to fetch them ?

I think the end result will be that you can't. Facebook doesn't use https, for example.

There are indicators for a possibly private site like the presence of a login field, but that still doesn't tell you whether the user is logged in to it.

You also can't find out whether a user is logged in to a site, because this information is private to the server, and most sites will maintain a session cookie no matter whether the user is logged in or not.

Also, there will be sites users don't want to end up in the thumbnails even though they're not private (*cough*YouPorn*cough*).

Comment: Yes, I already have an adult content filter, don't worry ! The login field could be a hint on an inaccurate but working solution, thank you !